# Hiding HTML5 Video Controls

Tags: javascript, css, html, video

im trying to implement a show and hide video element button

Here are my two buttons alongside Play/pause/Restart

```
  <div class="rightContent">
              <p class="center">Video Control Options</p>
              <p class="videoControls"> <input type="button" value="      Play       " onclick="video.play()"/> </p>
              <p class="videoControls"> <input type="button" value="     Pause       " onclick="video.pause();" /> </p>
              <p class="videoControls"> <input type="button" value="    Restart      " onclick="video.currentTime =0;"/> </p>
              <p class="videoControls"> <input type="button" value="  Show Controls  " onclick="Show()"/> </p>
              <p class="videoControls"> <input type="button" value="  Hide Controls  " /> </p>  
           </div>
```

My Javascript function to attempt to Hide the controls currently:

```
function hide(){
                            videoControls.setAttribute = ('style', 'display:none;')

                    }
```

however, this does not work.

Comment: use `videoControls.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');`

Answer (score 1):

Put the video element in a variable such as `myVideo`.

ex: `var myVideo = document.getElementById( 'myVideo' )`

Then:

```
   function hide(){
      video.removeAttribute( 'controls' );
   }
```

Here is a snippet showing it in action:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<body> 

<video id="myVideo" width="250" controls>
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

  <br>
  
<button onclick="hide()">Hide Controls</button>
<button onclick="show()">Show Controls</button>
  
<script>
   var myVideo = document.getElementById( 'myVideo' );

   function hide(){
     myVideo.removeAttribute( 'controls' );
   }

    function show(){
     myVideo.setAttribute( 'controls', '' );
   }
</script>

</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: This will work for built-in controls, but not custom controls.

Answer (score 0):

Your code sample is incomplete, but this is what I think is happening: you are trying to call `setAttribute` on a `NodeList`, which is not a method of `NodeList`.

```
// this is a node list, not a single node!
var videoControls = document.querySelectorAll(".videoControls"); 

// convert nodelist to array
var vcArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(videoControls);

// iterate over controls and hide each one.
vcArray.forEach(function(control){
  control.style.display = "none";
});
```